# Replace function in mysql not working

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table like this;

```
Lastname
MORALES
THOMPSON
SMITH
```

but I want to use the replace function to change all the lastname to another character like this:

- I want 'MORALES' to be replace with 'TEYE'

I tried this syntax;

```
select lastname, REPLACE(lastname, 'M', 'TEYE')
from customers;
```

but this is what i'm getting;

```
'MORALES    TEYEORALES'
```

Instead of

```
'MORALES    TEYE'
```

please I need help.
Thanks

Comment: I want every lastname that start with 'M' to replace with TEYE like this; MORALES      TEYE
MCGOVERN   TEYE
MCKENZIE      TEYE
MONTIASA      TEYE

Answer (score 0):

You told it only to replace `M`, not the whole name, that's what it did. If you want to replace the whole name, write:

```
SELECT lastname, REPLACE(lastname, 'MORALES', 'TEYE')
FROM customers
```

`REPLACE()` replaces substrings, so if there's a `lastname = AMORALES`, the result will be `ATEYES`. If you only want to replace it when it's the entire name, you can use:

```
SELECT lastname, IF(lastname = 'MORALES', 'TEYE', lastname)
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

not an expert in mySQL; but, it looks like you are getting what you asked for, the last name folowed by the last name where the "M" was replaced with "TEYE".

have you tried appending the string you want added? 
select lastname + " TEYE" (or some variation to concatenate in mySQL syntax.

if the last name only needs to be update if it currently equals "MORALES", you can most likely add a where (row selection) clause (something like where lastName = "morales") to filter the rows being updated